# Python function to convert data from a few columns as binary number to a single column in decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"action":[1,1,0,0], "drama":[1,0,1,1], "fantasy":[1,1,0,0], "sci-fi":[0,0,0,1]})
print(df)

df['result'] = df['action'].astype('string') + df['drama'].astype('string') + df['fantasy'].astype('string') + df['sci-fi'].astype('string')
print(df)

df['result'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 2))
print(df)
```

Is there a single function in python that can generate the result column?

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply()` can be used to apply a function over all rows and columns in a dataframe.

In you case:

```py
def customFunc(row):
    return int("".join([str(digit) for digit in row]), 2)
    
df.apply(customFunc, axis = 1) # axis = 1 implies apply on each row
```

The above result will produce

```
0    14
1    10
2     4
3     5
dtype: int64
```

Which you can then combine to your original dataframe.

```py
df["result"] = df.apply(customFunc, axis = 1)
```

which will give:

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks. But I’m looking if there is an existing function within some libraries (maybe sklearn), with an obscured name that does that. I got the data after applying an aggregate function (sum) after doing pd.get_dummies(), which is like a one-hot encoder in sklearn, now i want to combine the labels back into 1 column. So I’m thinking a built in function for that might probably exist. Just trying my luck here!